# Как добавить атрибут title при определенном условии?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить атрибут `title` только если в блоке обрезанный текст?

Если текст, не обрезанный, и помещается полностью `title` не нужен.

`120px` - это условная ширина, она может быть любая другая

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach( el => {
  el.setAttribute('title', el.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Обрезанный текст</div>
<div class="item">Необрезанный</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach( el => {
  if (el.scrollWidth > el.offsetWidth) {
    el.setAttribute('title', el.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Обрезанный текст</div>
<div class="item">Необрезанный</div>
```

Суть в том, что `scrollWidth` включает в себя содержимое контейнера в том числе и то, что не отображается, в отличие от `offsetWidth`. Соответственно если первое больше второго, значит, что произошло переполнение.

Идея взята [отсюда](https://qna.habr.com/q/1153828)